# mysql case statement, some work and some don't

Tags: mysql, case, mariadb

I try to run this in a stored procedure, but the problems seem to be with my case statements treating the "_registrations" and "_warnings" parts.

The idea is that all entries in the table have a type of registration, 0 or 1, and I want to, with a parameter, choose either all the registrations with a 1 or the one with a 2 or simply all of them, no matter of the value of the registration...

My attempt, that obviously fails

```
create procedure get_table_information3(_sort character(2), _start int, _page int, _seek varchar(64), _registrations varchar(64), _warnings varchar(64),  _categories varchar(64))
begin   
    select * from Students
    where  
        first_name like coalesce(concat('%', _seek, '%'), first_name) or
        last_name like coalesce(concat('%', _seek, '%'), last_name) or
        email like coalesce(concat('%', _seek, '%'), email) or
        comments like coalesce(concat('%', _seek, '%'), comments)  
            case when _registrations = 0 then and reg = 0,
        case when _registrations = 1 then and reg = 1 end,
        case when _warnings = 0 then and warning = 0,
        case when _warnings = 1 then and warning = 1 end,
        order by
        case when _sort = 'fa' then first_name end asc,
        case when _sort = 'fd' then first_name end desc,
    limit _start, _page;
end
```

The last 2 case-statements work (I know that since the procedure runs when removing the 4 first case statements). However, when adding these, everything failes.

I use MariaDB if that would be important to know. Error message:

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'and reg = 0 end,
        case when _registrations = 1 then and reg = 1 end,'

I have read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html but obviously there is something I don't understand.

Many thanks for your help.

Regards,
Niklas

---

Edit

I tried this as well:

`create procedure get_table_information3(_sort character(2), _start int, _page int, _seek varchar(64), _registrations varchar(64), _warnings varchar(64),  _categories varchar(64))
    begin

        select * from Students
        where

            first_name like coalesce(concat('%', _seek, '%'), first_name) or
            last_name like coalesce(concat('%', _seek, '%'), last_name) or
            email like coalesce(concat('%', _seek, '%'), email) or
            comments like coalesce(concat('%', _seek, '%'), comments)  and
 case _registrations
        when 0 then reg = 0, 
        when 1 then reg = 1,
        else reg in (0,1)
        end case
            order by
            case when _sort = 'fa' then first_name end asc,
            case when _sort = 'fd' then first_name end desc,
        limit _start, _page;
    end`

---

which should do what I want, but is "syntax error" although I think I have copied the syntax from the manual...

Comment: "case when _registrations = 0 ***then and*** reg = 0" does not look right. What are you actually trying to achieve with that line? "case when _registrations = 0 and reg = 0 then 1 else 0 end"?

Comment: well, when writing a normal "select * "-statement you usually separate the conditions by "and", "or", and so on. Would that not be needed here?

Comment: It's `CASE <condition> THEN <value if true> ELSE <value if false> END`, but in this case you're using `THEN AND` which - well - makes no sense. What is the condition, and what is the value you want if it's true?

Comment: see edit in original post for hopefully a clearer description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this captures exactly the logic you want, but it should give you an idea;

A `CASE` statement that checks if `reg=0` if `_registrations=0` should look like;

```
case when _registrations = 0 then reg = 0 ELSE 1 END
```

If `_registrations = 0`, this returns the value of `reg=0` else 1 (true), that is, if `_registrations` <> 0, the expression is always true.

That makes the entire query something like;

```
create procedure get_table_information3(_sort character(2), _start int, _page int, _seek varchar(64), _registrations varchar(64), _warnings varchar(64),  _categories varchar(64))
begin   
    select * from Students
    where  
       (first_name like coalesce(concat('%', _seek, '%'), first_name) or
        last_name like coalesce(concat('%', _seek, '%'), last_name) or
        email like coalesce(concat('%', _seek, '%'), email) or
        comments like coalesce(concat('%', _seek, '%'), comments)) AND 
        case when _registrations = 0 then reg = 0 ELSE 1 END AND
        case when _registrations = 1 then reg = 1 ELSE 1 END AND
        case when _warnings = 0 then warning = 0 ELSE 1 END AND
        case when _warnings = 1 then warning = 1 ELSE 1 END
        order by
        case when _sort = 'fa' then first_name end asc,
        case when _sort = 'fd' then first_name end desc
    limit _start, _page;
end
//
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I get less errors but still it won't run. Earlier it complained about syntax error in the case-statements, but now it says "1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 28". Line 28 is the line "limit _start, _page;", but I can't see what should be wrong there. (I have some more code before this part in the procedure, but that one is not causing any error, so I don't include that here)

Comment: I solved it, a silly typo in the file I have the procedure in to import it caused the last error. Thanks.